# How to give from and to date as filename foe csv file usong ag-grid angular

Tags: angular8, ag-grid

This is what am trying

```
 fromdate:any = moment.utc.format(yyyy mm dd hh mm )
OnButtonExport(){
FileName: '{{fromdate}}'
}
```

And same as to date , how could i achieve fromadate and todate as filename.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

method `exportDataAsCsv` accept a lot of params, one of these is: `fileName`.

you can apply any name.

List of all properties here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/csv-export/#csvexportparams

```
function getParams() {
  return {
    fileName: `from: ${new Date()}, to: ${new Date()}`,
  };
}

function onBtnExport() {
  gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv(getParams());
}
```